# Python pandas replace by None actually replaces with previous value

Tags: python, pandas

`pandas`' `replace` function replaces targeted values with another, as expected:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>>
>>> t = pd.Series([10,20,30])
>>> t
0    10
1    20
2    30
dtype: int64
>>> t.replace(to_replace=20, value=222)
0     10
1    222
2     30
dtype: int64
>>> from numpy import nan; t.replace(to_replace=20, value=nan)
0    10.0
1     NaN
2    30.0
dtype: float64
```

But when asking to replace by `None`, it replaces by the previous value.

```py
>>> t.replace(to_replace=20, value=None)
0    10
1    10
2    30
dtype: int64
```

What is the rationale behind this, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `to_replace` is a scalar and `value` is None. That behaviour is described in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

> The method to use when for replacement, when to_replace is a scalar,
> list or tuple and value is None.

The default method is `pad`, if you take a look at the [code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L4373-L4390). This probably happens because `None` is often used to express the absence of the parameter.

Comment: In fact, the only choices with `value=None` are some sort of fill: `'pad', 'ffill', 'bfill'` and not `None`.